# How can I exit to desktop from in-game?

Tags: pc, the-division-2

When I am in-game, the only menu option I have is to Logout, which then takes me to a loading screen, before ending up at the login screen.

Then I can click to Exit the game.

Is there an option which I'm missing here?

So far <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> seems the only way.

Comment: Console ports.. what do you expect? Consoles don't need to exit...

Comment: @Xander It's not a port. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7PMW8Lu80EE

Comment: Many games make you go back to login screen before exiting the game. I am not sure if divisioon 2 can be played offline, but if yes, then its a sacurity measure to make sure the game is saved before exiting. Another option is always the task manager though that takes longer than alt+f4

Comment: @DavidYell I guess the vid reached its audience.. Did you notice that the menu is made for consoles? Which PC game forces you to double click to do almost anything in the menu? Please...

Comment: @Xander true, the double clicking thing feels so weird at first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[A post on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/thedivision/comments/b0xmsi/psa_quit_in_chat_will_exit_the_game_without/), says that you can type `/quit` into chat to exit the game.